# Replacing different vlues with a value in notepad++

Tags: windows-7

I need to replace different values with a single value

e.g `<record num="1">`, `<record num="2">`, `<record num="3">` and so on to be replaced with `<br_part>` for all.

Comment: Use regex – replace the actual digits with \d in the search expression.

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve this with [regular expresisons](http://regular-expressions.info/).

#### Steps

1. Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>H</kbd>.
2. Use the following settings:

   ```
   Find what:    <record num="\d+">
   Replace with: <br_part>
   Search Mode:  Regular expression
   Wrap around:  checked
   ```
3. Click **Replace All**.

Here, `\d+` means a positive amount of digits.

Comment: Fantastic! it worked! Am so grateful. U just saved my ass! Many thanks

Comment: Glad I could help. If an answer solved your problem, you can *accept* it by clicking the check mark to its left.